# Quarkus is hiding resteasy exceptions

Tags: quarkus

I have run into a fairly annoying problem with Quarkus, that I cannot figure out how to solve.
I am using quarkus 2.4.1.Final. I am using the quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson module to create a REST service.
But when I send the service a post body with a bad format the client simply gets an empty HTTP 400 response back, and nothing is printed in the log on the server side. In this particular case I forgot to add the offset to an OffsetDateTime, so adding "+01:00" makes the service return correctly. Using micrometer metrics, I can see that the endpoint is being hit correctly both when the request is correct and when it isn't.

Hiding an exception from the developer is very close to heresy for me, as I would like to be able to see what the server fails with. I understand that we don't want the stack trace on the client side, but in this case the exception is missing from the server log.

Can anyone help me to convince Quarkus to not swallow my exceptions?

Comment: It is common that no exception are logged for a `BAD_REQUEST` when they occur in the deserialization layer (e.g. Spring does this aswell). If you need to see in the logs that a `BAD_REQUEST` occured, I recommend turning on [HTTP access logs](https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#configuring-http-access-logs).